# When does the data in the params get saved in the code below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't quite understand the logic for the code below. A new instance is created with the data entry by a user and the code goes on to say `if @item.save`. Don't you have to save the new instance BEFORE checking whether the instance was saved or not in `if @item.save`?

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description))

  if @item.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I don't get why the code isn't something like

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description))
  @item.save

  if @item.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@item.save` run validations and save the record if the validations passed successfully. Furthermore `save` returns `true` if the record was saved and `false` if the validations failed.

So it does both `saving` and returning the status of the saving operation. Therefore there is no need to do it yourself.

> By default, save always runs validations. If any of them fail the action is canceled and save returns `false`, and the record won't be saved.
>
> *Quote from the documentation of the [`save` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save)*.

Answer (score 0):

[`#save`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save) returns `true` or `false`. `true` if the object is saved successfully, `false` otherwise. This allows `@item.save` to be used as conditional expression in the `if` structure.

PS.: There is this other method [`#save!`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save%21) too. It returns `true` if the object gets saved or raises an error otherwise.